# Export docker container log to host path

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose, containers

I have a few containers running in my docker setup. I've added a restart policy as "always" to suddenly restart the container as soon as it got killed. But by this, I cannot get the container log which has the reason of the process termination which is the log which we can get by the command `"docker logs <container-id>"`.

Could someone please help me to map the docker container log (same to the above command output) to the host path? I have no idea about the location which the above `docker logs <container-id>` log is stored.

Answer (score 0):

The default logging driver JSON file located on the local disk of your Docker host.Please check the below hostpath to get the docker container logs stored.

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/[container-id]/[container-id]-json.log
```

You can change the default logging driver and to change please check this [document](https://sematext.com/guides/docker-logs/#:%7E:text=The%20default%20logging%20driver%20as,log.).

You can mount the volume of your containerized application logs file directory to hostpath directory and check using tail -f command.
For example,

```
docker run -it -v /tmp/app/tomcat:/usr/local/tomcat/logs tomcat
```

now you can tail the application logs from your host path.

```
tail -f /tmp/app/tomcat/logs.log
```

Comment: The output of This file is different than the "docker logs <cont-id>" command right? I'm trying to get the stdout of the container to the file in the host.

Comment: You can mount the volume of your containerized application logs file directory to hostpath directory and check using tail -f command.Please check the edited part